# Is there any way to AUTO trigger Dataflow jobs (that carries data from BigQuery to MySQL) when fresh data is loaded into BigQuery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am looking for the solution that auto triggers the dataflow jobs whenever BigQuery table receives a new data ?

Do not want to create a cron job which keep on looking for new changes in table.

Comment: AFAIK BigQuery does not support triggers. From where you are adding the data in BigQuery?

Comment: BigQuery triggers via Cloud Functions are in Alpha. You get a peek into them here (https://github.com/doitintl/bq-snitch): `gcloud beta functions deploy bq_informer --trigger-event google.cloud.bigquery.job.complete`. Not officially documented. Otherwise, you can hook in via Stackdriver logs + PubSub + Cloud Function + Dataflow (Template).

Comment: What is populating the your BigQuery Table? which process?

Comment: @GrahamPolley, not sure that we can communicate on this Alpha. My opinion is that there is no activity on it for several months, not sure that will be released a day...

Comment: Source for Bigquery table is multiple batch jobs (loading data from GCS to BQ) and each making an seperate log into stackdriver logging, I have tried stackdriver + pubsub + cloud function model too Graham but logs are more than 1 and its eventually executing cloud function more than once.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere It's part of gcloud now, albeit in alpha. People are stumbling across it and using it. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @aakash not sure what you're doing wrong. We've used that pattern many times before and it works well for us.

Comment: Out of the technical solution, when do you know that you can run your dataflow? How do you know that all the jobs are over? What is your "human" insight?

Comment: @guillaume, that is the only my concern, I need to run dataflow jobs only after the complete completion of all batch jobs (populating BigQuery table)

Comment: Ok, my question is simpler: if you have to do this manually, what do you see as metrics (logs or something else) to say "Ok, all integration done, let's start the dataflow"?

Comment: we don't track or see anything , our dataflow jobs are scheduled to run at specified time, irrespective of data loading.